# Undeclared identifier for Variadic Template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-templates

I'm still learning how to use variadic templates. Basically what I want to do is take an `STLContainer` that contains elements of type `String`. An STL container does not take a fixed number of parameters so I tried using a variadic template. If I understand correctly, I should be able to write this:

```
/* Take a container of String and return a string of those elements separated by commas.*/

template < template <typename String, typename ... Traits > class STLContainer >
String as_comma_list(const STLContainer<String, Traits> &container)
{
    String result;
    for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++)
    {
        result += *it;
        result += ",";
    }
    result.pop_back(); // pop last comma
    return result;
}
```

However the compiler (`Apple LLVM version 8.1.0`) spits out:

`error: use of undeclared identifier 'Traits'`

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: I ultimately have chosen @Pixelchemist's answer since it seems like the most "generic proof" solution and offered insight into my code. However, I would like to say that @Walter's answer is equivalently good. While @max66's answer was the simplest that fixed the problem, the original problem was that I tried to describe an STL container erroneously.

Comment: `Traits` isn't a type; it is a parameter pack. You need to expand the parameter pack:

`STLContainer<String, Traits...>`

Comment: Actually, you also don't have a parameter pack; you need `Traits` to be not in the template argument list of `STLContainer`, but of `as_comma_list`

Comment: STL containers cannot in general be described as `container<type,traits...>`. Consider `std::map<key,T,compare,alloc>`, which has `value_type=std::pair<key,T>` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your code would have to look like this:

```
template < template <class...> class STLContainer, class String, class ...Traits>
String as_comma_list(const STLContainer<String, Traits...> &container)
```

#### but let's look at the implications of your code:

1. The type `STLContainer` must take a template parameter. If I write a class `simplestringvector` (which is not generic I know, but nobody can't stop me :)) your code won't work for me.
2. The `STLContainer` type must provide `begin()` and `end()` members. (No free functions; no `std::begin` and `std::end`)
3. The `String` type must provide a `pop_back()` member.
4. The `String` type must have `operator+=` defined which must be capable of dealing with a string literal containing `char` (no `wchar_t`, no `char16_t`, ...).
5. And others that are less of an issue here.

#### The function can be more generic:

*No warranty as I'm quite tired but anyway...*

If your code requires the type to be iterable anyway you don't need to know the type of the String in the first place. You can get it as the decayed result of dereferencing the container iterator. By dragging `std::begin` and `std::end` into the scope you can enable [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) for free begin and end functions while still catching the member functions via the std functions.

First some headers and a helper class:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

namespace detail
{
    template<class ...> struct comma;
    template<> struct comma<char> 
    { static constexpr char c = ','; };
    template<> struct comma<wchar_t> 
    { static constexpr wchar_t c = L','; };
    template<> struct comma<char16_t> 
    { static constexpr char16_t c = u','; };
    template<> struct comma<char32_t> 
    { static constexpr char16_t c = U','; };
}
```

Now we try to implement `as_comma_list` with ADL enabled iteration and without any constraints with respect to the template layout of the container or string.

```
template <class C>
auto as_comma_list(C&& c)
{
    using std::begin; 
    using std::end;
    using string_type = std::decay_t<decltype(*begin(c))>;
    using char_type = std::decay_t<decltype(*begin(*begin(c)))>;
    string_type result;
    auto const ec = end(c);
    for (auto it = begin(c); it != ec; )
    {
        result += *it;
        if (++it != ec)
        {
            result += detail::comma<char_type>::c;
        }
        else break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

*Note: This example requires the String type to be iterable as well (which is very common) and it has a second branch in the loop which might be slower when dealing with billions of strings here.*

Comment: Wow thanks for the input! It really helps me a lot. However, I'm not entirely sure as to how I would call it? I mean I tried setting something such as `std::vector<std::string> > = v{"Hello", "World!"};`  `as_comma_list<std::vector<std::string> >(v)` With no luck compiling.

Comment: The error message is that it there is no conversion from `std::vector<std::string>  (aka 'vector<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >')` to `std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > > &&`

Comment: Maybe the compiler isn't deducing the template correctly?

Comment: So of course the compiler was spitting that out... I didn't notice that I was putting the implementation in a `.cpp` file. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @CarlosBrito : Just try `as_comma_list(v);` without any template parameter, as it will get deduced.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
template <template <typename...> class STLContainer,
          typename String, typename Traits> 
String as_comma_list(const STLContainer<String, Traits> &container)
```

?

But you need `Traits`?

I suppose that you can simplify your code as follows

```
template <template <typename...> class STLContainer, typename String> 
String as_comma_list(const STLContainer<String> &container)
```

Comment: Interesting concept that, *semplifiction* ;-)

Comment: @Walter - interesting, isn't it :( ? And I have used the spell checker. Thanks!

Comment: Although I must ask, referring to @Walter 's answer. Would this catch all of the STL containers? I tested it and the compiler succesfully deduces that `STLContainer` is a `std::vector<std::string>` and `String` is an `std::string`

Comment: @CarlosBrito - the template argument part intercept almost all STL container (exception: `std::array`, because the second template parameter of it isn't a type); but probably you don't want use all they in the same way; I mean: the `begin()` method for (by example) vectors and sets return an iterator that "points" to a contained (`String`) element; for maps (ordered, unordered, single or multi), `begin()` return an iterator that "points" to a `std::pair<T1, T2>` where `T1` and `T2` are the first and the second type arguments of `STLContainers`. See the Walter's answer also.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to write generic code in this way is bound to fail, because in general containers cannot be described as `container<T, traits...>`, think about `map<key, T, Compare, Allocator>`, which has `value_type=pair<key, T>`.

Instead, in C++, this type of generic programming is usually done via `iterators` (as all over the standard library), e.g.

```
template<typename It>
enable_if_t<is_same<string, typename iterator_traits<It>::value_type>::value,
            string>  // or use static_assert() in the function body
as_comma_list(It begin, const It &end)
{
    string result;
    for(; begin!=end; ++begin)
    {
        result += *begin;
        result += ",";
    }
    result.pop_back();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: As you mentioned, I tried @max66's solution with a container such as `map`; logically, I can't describe an STL container like I tried. Thanks for the help :-)